# IE8 Removing query strings on redirect

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs

I am building an Angular application and IE8 seems to be causing some awesome issues.

I have a location finder that is built into the clients website that will then launch over to the rental application when the user finds their desired location. Location data is sent over via query strings. It works fine in all modern browsers.

The client's website uses javascript to pop a new window and lead the user to the following link:
`https://rentabike.com/#/step-1?vendor=VendorType&locale=en_US&dealerid=DealerID`

This works fine in all major browsers, but then in IE, the window pops and IE strips all the query strings out and the url ends up being:
`https://rentabike.com/#/step-1`

Is there some IE quirk I am missing out on? I can't seem to figure out the root of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2), a `#` anchor must come AFTER a `?` query in a url, so

```
https://rentabike.com?vendor=VendorType&locale=en_US&dealerid=DealerID#/step-1
```

would be valid, while yours, with the `#` coming before the `?`, is not valid, so technically IE is being correct... for a change.